# WooCommerce - Display categories and its products on front page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

when the user visits my shop homepage he sees all the products which are in the shop. I want to change the view, so that the user sees:

**- Category 1**

*Products of cat 1*

**- Category 2**

*Products of cat 2*

How can I achieve this? I looked in `woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` and found this:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

But how can I hook into this, to create two different loops for cat 1 and cat 2?

Does somebody knows that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to query the products from a category:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-slug1' //Your category goes here
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'title',
);
$first_cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then just do a loop to print each product:

```
while ( $first_cat_query->have_posts() ) {
    $first_cat_query->the_post();
    echo '' . get_the_title() . '<br /><br />';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

And repeat the same to the next category, you'll need to adapt the template to make it compatible with the query.

Comment: Thanks - Okay. So I copy the archive-product.php and make an own version with the above snippet? I thought that there may be hooks that I can use...

Comment: Yes this works, products are the same like posts, they just have their post_type as product.